# Como hacer varias consultas con los mismo campos pero diferentes datos en las tablas?

Tags: sql-server

Qusiera juntar dos tablas con los mismo campos pero tienen direferentes cargados en sus tablas. ejemplo

```
select folio,'ALUMNO' AS ent_sal, observaciones 
from ALUMNO 
where activo='0'
```

Y

```
select folio,'MATERIA' as ent_sal, observaciones 
from MATERIA 
where activo='0'
```

Quiera que aparezca en una sola table Si alguien por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me da la impresión que quieres tener un único resultado?. En ese caso, solo necesitas usar `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT folio,
       'ALUMNO' ent_sal,
       observaciones
FROM ALUMNO
WHERE activo = '0'
UNION ALL
SELECT folio,
       'MATERIA' ent_sal,
       observaciones
FROM MATERIA
WHERE activo = '0';
```

Ahora, si quieres guardar ese resultado en una nueva tabla puedes usar `INTO`:

```
SELECT folio,
       'ALUMNO' ent_sal,
       observaciones
INTO dbo.NuevaTabla
FROM ALUMNO
WHERE activo = '0'
UNION ALL
SELECT folio,
       'MATERIA' ent_sal,
       observaciones
FROM MATERIA
WHERE activo = '0';
```

Comment: Buenos dias: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y tu ayuda, si me funciono, que Dios te bendiga y te siga llenado de sabiduria :)